# How to insert sequence value when using OracleBulkCopy in c# without before trigger in oracle

Tags: .net, oracle, copy, bulk

Using Oracle bulk copy in .net I am trying to bulk insert record to  a table.if the table contain primary key sequence column how can I insert the value to primary key column at the time of bulk insert.

How to set the sequence value at the time of bulk upload using OracleBulkCopy.

Without performance issue we need to do so trigger is not the correct way. Please let me know the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you're convinced that you don't want to use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to populate your primary key column with values obtained from the appropriate sequence, one option is to populate a collection of column values with numbers obtained from your sequence and then bind the column array to your bulk INSERT, just as you're doing for your other columns.

If you have a version of Oracle which allows it (12 or later, IIRC) you can also set the default value on your PK column to be `YOUR_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL`.

Answer (score 0):

from this link http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_how_to_add_sequence_to_oracle_table_column.htm

In Oracle 12c and beyond, you can associate a sequence directly with a table:  In this 
example, we associate the sequence with the table, directly in the create table statement.

```
create sequence my_test_id_seq increment by 1;

create table 
   my_test
(
  id        number default my_test_id_seq.nextval,
  name      varchar(10)
);

insert into 
   my_test 
(name) 
values 
   ('no sequence required!');
```